# Column added to .net DataTable does not get added to database Table

Tags: c#, dataset, addition

I'm new to this site and I started some time ago to program an application.
Right now I'm stuck at a problem and I have no idea how to solve it.

My problem is: I want to register every user in a new column, because I have to save a great amount of data for each of them (up to 1000 rows). Now I add a new column to the already existing table. But the thing is, if I want to retrieve this data I get an error that says there is no column called like this.

```
programDataSet.User.Columns.Add(textBoxUser.Text, typeof(Int32));

for (int i = 0; i < 4 && i < alchemieDataSet.User.Count; i++)
{
     programDataSet.User[i][textBoxUser.Text] = "1";
}

for (int i = 0; i < programDataSet.User.Count; i++)
{
     alchemieDataSet.User[i][textBoxUser.Text] = "0";
}

this.Validate();
this.userBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.programDataSet);
MessageBox.Show("Registration completed");
```

Does anyone have an idea what I made wrong?

Comment: Why new user in new column? it sound like a horr for me.

Comment: I have no  other idea how save all these data otherwise I have 1000 colums at the beginning

Comment: No, i am almost sure that your database model is incorrect. I have never seen any purpose why to treat user as a colum - one user is one record more in the users table. You can share with your database diagram and i can help you with the designing. Of course it's everything beside of your problem, but this is not a good idea to start programming with the table with 1000 atributes.

Comment: Okay, so at first thank you for your fast respons. do you have any other idea how i can store these data? The data is only a true or false (1 or 0) per row, but 1000 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with everyone that there are big red flags with data architecture.

But to your specific question, DataSets and Adapters do not change table columns in a target database.  They only change rows.

You have to update the columns separately.

Comment: Ahh oke. I didn't knew that

Comment: no problem.  Maybe check out relational database models if you get a chance.... might mage things easier later